# Frothing milk more quietly?

Tags: coffee, milk, espresso

I have a Mr. Coffee BVMC-ECM260 espresso maker. I'm kind of getting the hang of frothing it (i.e. I can make a decent cup of frothed milk) but every time it makes that loud "screaming" noise that I've seen others describe. I've tried different techniques, putting the wand in close to the surface, close to the bottom, etc. but it makes the same noise. I live in a small apartment building where the walls are very thin and making loud screaming noises with my espresso maker on a regular basis is not really ideal for me. Should I just go back to a drip coffee maker, or could there be a problem with the way I'm frothing the milk?

Answer (score 0):

Try a [magnetically stirred milk frother](https://www.google.com/search?q=magnetic%20milk%20frother&tbm=isch)

They use a small jug sitting on top of a heating element, with a rotating magnet below the heater. A small magnetic stirrer dropped into the jug therefore spins, and froths the milk, nearly as well as a steamer does

The Nespresso one is crap